# ILGenerator, make decision on return value of null

Tags: ilgenerator

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, _compactBinaryReader_ReadObject);
```

this function is called and at a special condition a return value of 'null' is provided.

if that value is null i have to take a decision whether to jump on to a label or not

using after the method call

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, DECISION);
```

gives me an exception "JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation." when i call that function, the code builds correctly though.

tried OpCodes.Brfalse too.

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found reasonS to the above problem,

one thing which should be understood that when an exception of 
'CLR: Verification for Runtime Code Generation'
is thrown it means the code written is not in the correct format and when it is evaluated by the assembler it does not accept the written code, problem is usually because of stacks having extra values or less.

"JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation." is thrown when at runtime it was expecting something else we provide something else in value or when stack has something else when something else was required.

In short, the later exception is thrown at runtime and the other is thrown when pre Run conditions are not met.

anyways i found the reason, i had some values still present on stack that i did not pop if Condition was met, so the POP OpCode did the trick, and by the way for me the Dup OpCode never worked out, it always pushes a null value on stack rather than duplicating the top most value.